# Numerical integration with a parameter over a data set in Mathematica

Tags: numerical-integration

I want to do numerical integration in Mathematica over a large dataset like:

Here I am giving the link for sharing the data: https://pastebin.com/VQQnBuPE

The y values of the data are function of h.

After the integration, I want to plot the resulting function as a function of h. How can I do that?

Comment: If I understand correctly what you want to do the trick is to NOT consider `NIntegrate` directly. For example, this `NIntegrate[c x, {x, 0, 2}]` yields an error. On the other hand, if you write `gg[c_] := NIntegrate[c x, {x, 0, 2}]
` and then you run `gg[1]` you can get an answer without any errors.

Comment: Also, you mentioned that you wanted to integrate over the data. Does this mean that you want to map the points $x_i, y_i$ to a specific function and then integrate the function or just do integrals of the form $\int x_i$ from some initial value to some final one and similarly for the $y_i$?

Comment: If it's numeric data `{{x1, y1}, {x2, y2},...}`, then `f = Integrate[Interpolation[data][x], x]` and `Plot[f, {x, Min[data[[All, 1]]], Max[data[[All, 1]]]}]`. Otherwise, I don't understand, which is probably the case. I certainly don't understand how to plot a function of c when c is a constant, unless it's a single point. Show a small segment of your data, and it should help clarify.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I guess that the scope is to examine the behavior under different values of `c` and try to do a fit to data. A MWE of what I have understood, you start by examining $c=1$ then $c=2$, etc depending on the allowed values of $c$. (??)

Comment: @DiSp0sablE_H3r0 I have no clue. You could be right. But the language in the question is so far from the usual way to describe fitting a model to data that I would guess it's not about that. And I won't be surprised if I'm wrong, because: I have no clue. I don't think the OP is going to get much help until the question is clarified, and some of the data is given so that it's clear what there is to work with.

Comment: @MichaelE2 100% with you that the OP needs further clarifications in order to become more transparent and we can get a better idea on what we are working.

Comment: @MichaelE2  The data looks like data={{0.198, 3.4*c^2/(1+c) }, {0.218, 9.2*c^2/(1+c)}, {0.319, 8.5 *c^2/(1+c)},.......}. I have tried with Interpolation[data] and then Integ[c_]=NIntegrate[func[x], {x, x_min, x_max}]. I want to plot Integ[c] for c=0 to c=1000. But, I am getting error. How to resolve that issue

Comment: @DiSp0sablE_H3r0 The data looks like data={{0.198, 3.4*c^2/(1+c) }, {0.218, 9.2*c^2/(1+c)}, {0.319, 8.5 *c^2/(1+c)},.......}. I have tried with Interpolation[data] and then Integ[c_]=NIntegrate[func[x], {x, x_min, x_max}]. I want to plot Integ[c] for c=0 to c=1000. But, I am getting error. How to resolve that issue

Comment: Thank you. You should edit the question to include it.  So the data is not completely numeric, but has a symbolic variable `c` in the second column.  That's helpful to know. I'd use `Integrate` rather than `NIntegrate` if `func` is an `InterpolatingFunction`. I'll have to try it on the symbolic data, which I don't recall ever doing.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelE2. I will edit the question and I will upload the data.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Is it possible to attach the the mathematica notebook here? I have a large data. How can I upload the data here?

Comment: You can paste the data in pastebin.com and put the link here. But I wonder, can you not add just 10 or 20 data points. Alternatively, you could check whether my answer works on your data set. If it does, then problem solved and you could just edit into the question the three data points from your comment. There is no need for us to have exactly all your data, unless it turns out that the problem is buried in the data in some data point.

Comment: I have used your answer to do the integration with my data. It would not work. Okay. Here I am pasting 10 or 20 data points.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Here I am pasting the link of the data set  <https://pastebin.com/VQQnBuPE>. I have edited the post too. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

With so little data supplied, `Interpolation` will complain as expected.

```
data = {{0.198, 3.4*c^2/(1 + c)}, {0.218, 9.2*c^2/(1 + c)},
  {0.319, 8.5*c^2/(1 + c)}};

func = Interpolation[data];
{xmin, xmax} = First@func["Domain"];
```

> Interpolation::inhr: Requested order is too high; order has been reduced to {2}.

```
integ[c_] = Integrate[func[x], {x, xmin, xmax}]
```

> ```
> (*  0. + (1.44451 c^2)/(1. + c)  *)
> ```

With the data supplied, `integ[c]` quickly approaches its asymptotic behavior $\sim$ `1.44451 c`, so I just show the initial graph.

```
Plot[integ[c], {c, 0, 2}]
```

> [image]